# Ruby on Rails: how do I catch ActiveRecord::Rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller, I have code that looks like the following:

```
    @mymodel.transaction do 
      for a in arr
        @mymodel.some_method(a)
      end
    end
```

in @mymodel#some_method I could throw an `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception which in the db does what it needs to do, however I then simply get an HTTP 500 and no way to catch the exception to let the user know in an elegant way what went wrong.

I've tried wrapping @mymodel.transaction do in a begin/rescue block, but that won't do it either. What's the best way to catch the exception so I can present the proper view to the user?

Comment: Doesn't the transaction block catch the rollback exception? That's what it's supposed to do…

Answer (score 3):

From the `ActiveRecord::Base` documentation:

> Normally, raising an exception will cause the `transaction` method to rollback the database transaction *and* pass on the exception. But if you raise an ActiveRecord::Rollback exception, then the database transaction will be rolled back, without passing on the exception.

A small example:

```
class ThrowController < ApplicationController
  def index
      status = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback.new
      end

      Rails.logger.info "followed transaction"
  end
end
```

then:

```
>> c = ThrowController.new.index
=> "followed transaction \n"
```

As you can see, the `ActiveRecord:::Rollback` exception is swallowed by the `transaction` block.

It seems to me that something else is going on with your code that we're not aware of.

Comment: Have tried that also, still no go, get an http 500 because the exception isn't being handled.

Comment: try the begin rescue outside the transaction block

Comment: I reworked my answer with a better example from the documentation. I think we need more code from you that exhibits the 500 error.

Comment: I wonder if you can do `rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback` without throwing it. What do you think? For handling situations when the transaction is cancelled.